# Are anonymous types in c# accessible through reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, anonymous-types

As the name of the anonymous type is compiler generated, so is it accessible through reflection?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. As far as the CLR/framework is concerned, they're normal types. In fact, you can do some [interesting things](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/12/09/quot-magic-quot-null-argument-testing.aspx) with reflection on anonymous types...

The current C# compiler actually creates a *generic* type though, so that two anonymous types which both just have a "Foo" property of different types will share a generic type, but have different closed types.

Comment: I guess the compiler give the anonymous type a name, am i right?

Comment: @Benny: Yes. It gives it an *unspeakable name* - one which is valid to the CLR, but not to other C# code, so it can't introduce naming collisions.

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you have an updated location for that link?  Or a better source for newer information?  I tried it and it's now dead.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff: Give it a try now - I've fixed it.